# find text from multiple div having same class jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
    <div class="textbox-fill-mid">
        <div style="display:none;" class="bbit-cs-id">171</div>
        <div style="cursor:pointer;" >adad</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox-fill-mid">
        <div style="display:none;" class="bbit-cs-id">11</div>
        <div style="cursor:pointer;" >adad</div>
    </div>
    <div class="textbox-fill-mid">
        <div style="display:none;" class="bbit-cs-id">41</div>
        <div style="cursor:pointer;" >adad</div>
    </div>
```

my url : `localhost/pr1/ev.php?eid=41`

```
if(isset($_GET['eid']))
{
    echo "<div id='notifi_event_id'>".$_GET['eid']."</div>";
}
```

using jquery

```
var notifi_event_id=$('#notifi_event_id').text(); // having 41
```

I know that all elements with different values are located into .bbit-cs-id, but I don't know how to find any of the .bbit-cs-id having 41 or not ,

Comment: same ids??? that invalid HTML...

Comment: id's have to be unique across the html. Bad HTML.
Use classes instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find an element containing a specific text value, you need to use `filter()`:

```
var notifi_event_id = $('#notifi_event_id').text(); // = 41
var $bbit = $('.bbit-cs-id').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == notifi_event_id;
});

// you can then do something with the matching element:
$bbit.addClass('foo');
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5AM4e/)

Answer (score 3):

Hope this also will help you

```
var is41=false;
$('.bbit-cs-id').each(function(i,data){
    if($(this).text()=='41')
        is41=true;
});
alert(is41);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ilaiyaraja/AE9zy/1/

Comment: simple and working, welcome to StackOverflow @Ilaiyaraja

Answer (score 2):

You can use this syntax to access each div :

```
var cases = $('div.bbit-cs-id').each(function()
{
    // You access each object with : $(this)
    // So you can access Text with the following line :
    console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) operator to look for text content:

```
if($('.bbit-cs-id:contains(41)').length){
    console.log($('.bbit-cs-id:contains(41):first')); //print the first element.

    //update the parent or the sublink.
    $('.bbit-cs-id:contains(41):first').next().css({color:'red'});
    $('.bbit-cs-id:contains(41):first').parent().css({border:'1px solid gray'});
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AM4e/)

**Note**:
it if this `div` is just to hold the ID of something ... why not use `data` attribute to the container?:

```
<div class="textbox-fill-mid" data-id="41"> 
   <div style="cursor:pointer;" >adad</div>
</div>  
<script>
    $('.textbox-fill-mid[data-id=41]');
</script>
```